# Linking published app to firebase console

Tags: android, firebase

I have android app linked to firebase, while developing on debug, the app works well and I can read data back and forth, for this I was using a debug SHA1 certificate, synced on both the app and firebase console.

[image]

I then

- generated a signed apk
- obtained the release SHA1 certificate, synced it on firebase console and
- downloaded the new `google-services.json` file.
- published the app in alpha mode for test

However, the published app is not able to read data from the database ... related posts suggest to use the release SHA1 cert, which I have already done and confirmed

[image]

What am I missing or doing incorrect here? Also how can I know if the generated SHA1 certificate is a debug or release one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to add release SHA1 on firebase, I guess sha1 you provided is for debug app.

Comment: I've added the release SHA1 certificate on firebase console. This brings another question how can I know if the certificate is a debug or release?

Comment: When you generate signing certificate there will be two section one for debug and another one for release. May I know how you are generating sha1.

Comment: This is how I'm generating the SHA1 release cert - `keytool -list -v -keystore {keystore_name} -alias {alias_name}`

Comment: Above is also correct, but you can try to generate from android studio using signing request. For this go to Gradel toolbar on the right and expand Run Configuration. You will find signingReport and check if both sha1 key is same for release or not. If it is different one then update it on firebase console and generate release apk. Kindly check and confirm. Hoping It will work.

Comment: actually, that is what I did I used android studio to generate, but now using the code I've posted in the comment generates a different SHA1 certificate, I just need to know which one is the release and which one is the debug

Comment: You must get variants on signingReport
e.g: debug/release

Comment: Ah, I've seen it, `Variant: releaseUnitTest`, much thanks